# Uploading Image/Photo in struts1

Tags: image, image-uploading, struts-1

I would like to get Coding To Upload Image(.jpg)/Photo to Server Machine using Struts1.x and
mySQL database I have the code for File Upload Instead.

Let me know what tweaking is required here. TC

Code for File Upload :----

public class FileUploadForm extends ActionForm{

```
private FormFile file;

public FormFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(FormFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

@Override
public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping,
   HttpServletRequest request) {

    ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

    if( getFile().getFileSize()== 0){
       errors.add("common.file.err",
        new ActionMessage("error.common.file.required"));
       return errors;
    }

    //only allow textfile to upload
    if(!"text/plain".equals(getFile().getContentType())){
        errors.add("common.file.err.ext",
         new ActionMessage("error.common.file.textfile.only"));
        return errors;
    }

        //file size cant larger than 10kb
    System.out.println(getFile().getFileSize());
    if(getFile().getFileSize() > 10240){ //10kb
       errors.add("common.file.err.size",
        new ActionMessage("error.common.file.size.limit", 10240));
       return errors;
    }

    return errors;
}
```

}

Action Class:--

public class FileUploadAction extends Action{

```
@Override
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {

    FileUploadForm fileUploadForm = (FileUploadForm)form;

    FormFile file = fileUploadForm.getFile();

    //Get the servers upload directory real path name
    String filePath = 
           getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") +"upload";

    //create the upload folder if not exists
    File folder = new File(filePath);
    if(!folder.exists()){
        folder.mkdir();
    }

    String fileName = file.getFileName();

    if(!("").equals(fileName)){  

        System.out.println("Server path:" +filePath);
        File newFile = new File(filePath, fileName);

        if(!newFile.exists()){
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
          fos.write(file.getFileData());
          fos.flush();
          fos.close();
        }  

        request.setAttribute("uploadedFilePath",newFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        request.setAttribute("uploadedFileName",newFile.getName());
    }
    return mapping.findForward("success");
}
```

}

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: the above code works fine. TC . I have verified

Comment: Refere this link for Image/Photo Upload in struts1.x http://www.roseindia.net/struts/strutsfileuploadandsave.shtml Now , I am trying for multiple files upload in Single go using tweaking this code. will keep posted on the same.
Tc & Rgds
ACJ